# how to get month and year value

Tags: forms, datetime

I am using following code to build the select box for Month and year

```
$form['billing']['expiry_db'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_select',
    '#title' => t('Expiry Date'),
    '#default_value' => date('m Y'),
    '#date_format' => 'm Y',
    '#date_label_position' => 'within',
    '#date_year_range' => '0:+20',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="field-wrapper-w1">'
);
```

I am passing following value in database

```
$form_state['values']['billing']['expiry_db']['month']
```

and

```
$form_state['values']['billing']['expiry_db']['year']
```

but it is only showing value '2' for month and value '2' for year. However I am selecting month 'December' which has value '12' in HTML. Please help

Answer (score 1):

The value for #default_value must have the `date()` format "Y-m-d H:i:s"; the value returned in `$form_state` is a string.

In your case, the code you should use is the following one.

```
  $form['billing']['expiry_db'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_select',
    '#title' => t('Expiry Date'),
    '#default_value' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    '#date_format' => 'm Y',
    '#date_label_position' => 'within',
    '#date_year_range' => '0:+20',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#prefix' => '<div class="field-wrapper-w1">',
  );
```

If the form has #tree set to `TRUE`, then `$form_state['values']['billing']['expiry_db']` a string such as `'2020-05'` for May, 2020.

As far as I can see, the value of #date_format is only used to understand which components of a date must be returned, but the format of the returned value is always the same. Changing #date_format to `'Y-H:s'` the returned value is `'2020 00:00'`. In you case, the code to get the month, and the year is the following one.

```
list($year, $month) = explode('-', $form_state['values']['billing']['expiry_db']);
```

#### References

- [_date_api_element_info()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/_date_api_element_info/7)